# Why does overflow-x:hidden create "borders"?

Tags: css

I have a wrapper element which I want to have a fixed width and make it un-scrollable to the sides (it's meant for mobile)
When I give the wrapper overflow-x:hidden I get a strange "borders" at the top and bottom.
you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/ilyaD/nzGxf/3/
why is that and how can i remove them?

==updated the fiddle==
the overflow hidden does hide the elements that are wider then the wrapper but creates some kind of inner scrolled element with the frame that appears in the screenshot and a persistent scroll-bar

[image]

Comment: I don't see any borders in Chrome, Firefox, or IE.

Comment: @j08691 Remove the line "overflow-x: hidden;" in the CSS. With the overflow there is a 1" yellow bar at the top and similar bar at bottom.

Comment: Consider posting a "good" case as well as a separate fiddle.

Comment: I'm still not seeing any border, or border-like space in the jsFiddle example. What browser and OS are you seeing this in?

Comment: @j08691 take a look at the screenshot i added, you don't see it? i see it on chrome and iphone safari

Answer (score 0):

If what you're talking about is the space in between each box, the class "box" is inline-block, so the line-breaks in the markup are interpreted as implied spaces. Place all the inline-block markup on a single line `<div></div><div></div>...` and the "space" between will collapse.

Answer (score -1):

To add to Jim H.'s answer, you could alternatively `display: block; float: left` the divs rather than `display: inline-block` them